# pyfyre TypeError: WSGIContainer.environ()

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications

I want to create a simple reactive web application by using pyfyre. Right after installing with the step-by-step manual on their website, I encounter following errors

This is my console output in PyCharm:

```
(Interface_PyFyre) alice-iMac:clickParkour alice$ pyfyre run
Generating package src
adding index package False
adding settings package False
adding pyfyre.events package False
adding pyfyre package True
adding pyfyre.utils package False
adding pyfyre.styles package False
adding pyfyre.exceptions package False
adding pyfyre.router package False
adding pyfyre.states package False
adding pyfyre.nodes.lists package False
adding pyfyre.nodes package True
adding pyfyre.nodes.links package False
adding pyfyre.nodes.futures package False
adding pyfyre.nodes.widgets package False
adding pyfyre.nodes.inputs package False
adding pyfyre.nodes.buttons package False
adding pyfyre.nodes.base package False
adding pyfyre.presets.loading package False
adding pyfyre.presets package True
adding pyfyre.presets.errors package False
20 files
done
[I 230509 11:21:40 server:335] Serving on http://localhost:5500
[I 230509 11:21:40 handlers:62] Start watching changes
[I 230509 11:21:40 handlers:64] Start detecting changes
[E 230509 11:21:43 web:1871] Uncaught exception GET / (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:5500', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/alice/anaconda3/envs/Interface_PyFyre/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1763, in _execute
        result = self.prepare()
      File "/Users/alice/anaconda3/envs/Interface_PyFyre/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3129, in prepare
        self.fallback(self.request)
      File "/Users/alice/anaconda3/envs/Interface_PyFyre/lib/python3.10/site-packages/livereload/server.py", line 133, in __call__
        WSGIContainer.environ(request), start_response)
    TypeError: WSGIContainer.environ() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
[E 230509 11:21:43 web:2344] 500 GET / (::1) 2.97ms
```

this is what the browser displays me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alice/anaconda3/envs/Interface_PyFyre/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1763, in _execute
    result = self.prepare()
  File "/Users/alice/anaconda3/envs/Interface_PyFyre/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3129, in prepare
    self.fallback(self.request)
  File "/Users/alice/anaconda3/envs/Interface_PyFyre/lib/python3.10/site-packages/livereload/server.py", line 133, in __call__
    WSGIContainer.environ(request), start_response)
TypeError: WSGIContainer.environ() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

I tried to resolve it by the response code 500. Since this is rather a generic "catch-all" response, I don't have any idea how to go further from this point.

Also profunded assumption would be welcome
Thanks in advance

*Edit 09/05: removing pictures for code block*

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 6.3 of tornado `WSGIContainer.environ` is [`No longer a static method.`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer.environ). Pyfyre will need to update their code to use the new syntax.

For now, you can solve that by specifying `tornado<6.3.0` in your requirements file.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you! helped a lot at least to know that the error wasn't on my side